# How to silently revalidate cached data in Apollo Client in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have an implementation of Apollo client's `useQuery` in my React code that I need to update itself every time the user navigates to the page. 
I tried using the query's `refetch` function but it triggers the loading state of the query, hence making the cache useless. 
What i need is for the data in cache to be rendered initially, but have it run the graphQl query in the background and update the cache if the data returned from the query is different from what has been saved on the cache. Basic cache revalidation. 
How do I go about implementing this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetchPolicy` and `nextFetchPolicy` in useQuery

for eg.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS, {
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network', // Used for first execution
  nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network', // Used for subsequent executions
});
```

You can refer this page for more understanding of fetchPolicy - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies

Comment: Thanks, Niks. But seems this configuration still triggers the loading state.